# Typing effect module in python

Tags: python

[image: example of printed text with colors]

I am searching this module how to find or who can know this module please help, i am For 2 days I've been looking for this but I couldn't find it, thanks in advance friends.

Let me introduce the module:

```
print("example text", interval=0.05, color=red_to_blue)
```

I think it worked with this command, it had a smooth color transition and text effect.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for the [`pystyle`](https://github.com/billythegoat356/pystyle) module..

```
from pystyle import *
Write.Print("example text", Colors.blue_to_purple, interval=0.5)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Yes this module. Thank you thank you.

Comment: @driffed please consider accepting the answer :)